# problems with msg files created using Outlook

Tags: file, outlook, format, ascii, msg

I am trying to use a program and the input is supposed to be msg files that are "uuencoded or pgp ascii-armored text file". I created plain text emails and saved them as `.msg` files using Outlook.

However the program throws an error that says `Message not in PGP or uuencode format. Could not find "begin" at top of file.` I couldn't figure out what the problem is. Can someone please help? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

MSG files are binary OLE storage files (IStorage) - open an MSG file with Notepad to see what's inside.

Comment: Thanks. The email I wrote had only one sentence, but the msg file I created using office 365 outlook has about 80 lines of characters like this `  __substg1.0_0E1D001F-◊@¸ilÁ0DﬂÂoÊÁèËü«GTML‰Äop ¸ofLÅ◊0Î/Ï?ÌOÓ_áÔosR ttomˇÚÛÙ/ı?°H◊1Íp(Web)˜ˇ˘˙˚/”¸?sAc”qy˜Ôˇˇ/?E‡Î}êﬂ/?O_sCÉ0Îˇ/?
O_eR0ˇ` don't look like binary to me..

Comment: It doesn't look binary? What would a binary file look like in your opinion? :-)

Comment: It depends at how you look at the file. Look at the file in your favorite binary editor. Text files have only ASCII characters, binary files aave bytes outside of that range.

Comment: Be as it may, what exactly do you need? An EML (MIME) file? Give an example of what you actually want.